# What is the symbol for a a result that overflows?

Tags: notation, computer-arithmetic

Suppose we have an unsigned $8$ bit number (min=$0$, max=$255$).

the result of "$200 + 200$" overflows to $144$

the result of "$100 - 200$" (under?)overflows to $156$

Is there are mathematical symbol to represent this?

Comment: It seems like you are talking about modular arithmetic, unless I am misinterpreting your notion of "overflow"

Comment: Do you *need* a symbol? The phrase `"200+200" overflows to 144` is clear.

Comment: @ThomasGrubb yes modular arithmetic

Comment: @lhf that doesnt work for all cases.. like where you dont know what the result will be "x + y (mod 256)"

Answer (score 1):

You can denote it using $x \pmod {y+1}$ as long as your minimum is $0$ and the maximum value is $y$.

Example $1$:
$$200 + 200 = 400 = 256 + 144$$

$$200 + 200 \equiv 144 \pmod {256}$$

Example $2$:
$$100 - 200 = - 100 = -256 + 156$$

$$100 - 200 \equiv -100 \pmod {256}$$

Answer (score 0):

"Overflow" is the wrong term here:

> to flow over the edge or brim of (a receptacle, container, etc.).

<sub>ref: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/overflow</sub>

In the cited example, you have an integer that is too large to fit in the data format you are using to represent an integer: specifically 8-bit binary numerals.

The operation you are describing is not *overflow*, but a common reaction to overflow that a lot of computer environments practice: to store just the least significant 8 bits of the (two's complement) result.

In computer lingo this is sometimes called "wrapping", envisioning the number line being wrapped up around a circle whose circumference has the 256 possible values you can store.

Mathematically, this turns out to be the same as computing a reduced representative *modulo* 256. Or more accurately, you aren't performing addition of integers, but you are performing addition modulo 256.

To specify that the operation and the result are equivalent modulo 256, one writes

$$ 200 + 200 = 144 \pmod{256} $$

Sometimes, people use the *remainder* operator (which, confusingly, is often notated as $\bmod$), and would write

$$ (200 + 200) \bmod 256 = 144 $$

Some standards even explicitly invoke this mathematical operation — `+` on 8-bit types isn't defined to be addition of integers, but addition modulo 256.

---

Incidentally, some computing environments also practice other behaviors; e.g. you can often ask for *saturating* arithmetic, under which $200 + 200$ would simply produce the maximum value $255$. The C and C++ standards decree that overflow (of signed integer types) *shall not happen*; if you write a program where it does, undefined behavior results meaning the standard allows the program to do anything at all.